# number set to DateTime in vb

Tags: vb.net, datetime

is there anyway to convert "20180717" in to datetime "MM dd yyyy" format in vb.net
im reading csv file and pick up values related to date all date values are in like "20180717" format need to store thoses in datatable DateTime column in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx). This method doesn't throw an `Exception` in case the input isn't valid:

```
Dim dtValue As DateTime

If DateTime.TryParseExact("20180717", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtValue) Then
    'The input is a valid date in specified format. The parsed date is now in dtValue
Else
    'The input isn't a valid date (in specified format).
End If
```

Comment: @SithumWitharana Please accept Sebastian's answer as the answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ParseExact(csvstring,"yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM dd yyyy")

Comment: Doesn't need the ToString, since they want it as a `DateTime`.

Comment: @AFriend question was ambiguous as it says 'in to datetime "MM dd yyyy" format' - since a format string was given, I figured it was better to include ToString and the OP can work out how to remove that if needed